# Hibernate: mapping same column for two different classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm working on a legacy system, that doesn't have a proper unit test, neither a any  so I need to be very careful about any change that I do in the system.

The basic scenario that I have is:
I got a Person that has a ManyToOne relationship with Address, I can't change this relationship. But know there are types of Address, for instance: billing address and post address.

```
public class Person {

@Id
@Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "PERSON_NAME")
private String personName;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
private Address address;

getters and setters
```

address class

```
public class Address {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "STREET_1_NAME")
private String street1Name;

@Column(name = "STREET_2_NAME")
private String street2Name;

getters and setters
```

I'm thinking to add the column ADDRESS_TYPE to ADDRESS table, but I'm struggling on how to implement it. I just want to have a new attribute postalAddress of type Address and get the postalAddress as easy as just getPostalAddress.

Comment: Just to clarify: the relationship is a many-to-one from person to address? Each person has one address and each address can belong to many people. Is this correct? From your question it sounds like you want it the other way round. Each person has multiple addresses: billing, postal etc.

Comment: Yes, your're right, that's what I have and what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Alan, your suggestion helped but I end up using InheritanceType because of compatibility with legacy code.

My Address class now looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="ADDRESS_TYPE",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER
)
@DiscriminatorValue("null")

public class Address  {
```

My PostalAddress looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="2")
public class PostalAddress extends Address {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "INSURED_ID")
    private Insured insured;

    public void setInsured(Insured insured) {
        this.insured = insured;
    }

    public Insured getInsured() {
        return insured;
    }

}
```

So, for those addresses inserted in the past without a type I'm assuming `null` and for compatibility the new ones will be 'null' as well, just the PostalAddress will be '2'.

And my Person class looks like

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
private Address address;

@Transient
private PostalAddress postalAddress;
```

I know it sounds odd, but I've been asked to have a relationship Person 1 - N PostalAddress.

Answer (score 0):

hust add :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "POSTAL_ADDRESS_ID")
private Address postalAddress;
```

this will add a new column to your `Person` table managing the relation.
No need to add `ADDRESS_TYPE` to `ADDRESS` table since it will be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my previous comment sounds to me like you want a one-to-many from Person to Address using a Map.

Add the address_type column as you suggested and create an Enum AddressType (POSTAL, BILLING):

In Person:

```
//there are various MapKey annotations however, without testing I think these are what you need
@OneToMany
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.String) //tells Hibernate we want the type to contain BILLING/POSTAL etc rather than the ENUM ordinals (0,1 etc)
@MapKeyColumn(name ="address_type")
private Map<AddressType, Address) addresses;

public Address getPostalAddress(){
return addresses.get(AddressType.POSTAL);
}

public Address getBillingAddress(){
return addresses.get(AddressType.Billing);
}

//or even
public Address getAddress(AddressType type){
return addresses.get(type);
}
```

- I am assuming that the addresses table has a FK to persons.